# Materialize Collapsible Dont Open with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I'm inserting Collapsible into HTML as soon as it receives JSON and adds the information to it.

But Collapsible does not open,
It only opens if I insert the same in HTML itself, but I can not leave it as I have to generate the results from JSON and thus create the Collapsibles for each object.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function GeneratePeoples__(objJSON){
  for(cat in objJSON.categories){
    document.getElementById('peoples-information').innerHTML +=
    '<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">' +
      '<li>' +
        '<div class="collapsible-header"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><strong>People ('+ cat +')</strong></div>' +
        '<div class="collapsible-body white">' +
          '<ul class="collection">' +
            '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
              '<i class="fa fa-male circle blue" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
              '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Type of Categories</span>' +
              '<p><strong>'+ objJSON.categories[cat].name +'</strong></p>' +
              '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>+ objJSON.categories[cat].score + '%' +</strong></span>' +
                '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Score</strong></span>' +
              '</a>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</li>' +
    '</ul>';
  }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="peoples-information"></div>
```

Comment: Can you see an error(s) in your console? Have you checked the console for some error(s) in your JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

**WORKING:**

```
function GenerateCelebrities__(objJSON){
      for(cat in objJSON.categories){
        for(cel in objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities){
          document.getElementById('celebrities-information').innerHTML +=
          '<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">' +
            '<li>' +
              '<div class="collapsible-header"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><strong>Celebrity ('+ cap++ +')</strong></div>' +
              '<div class="collapsible-body white">' +
                '<ul class="collection">' +
                  '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                    '<i class="fa fa-star circle yellow-text myDiv" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                    '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Celebrity Name</span>' +
                    '<p><strong>'+ objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].name +'</strong></p>' +
                    '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                      '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>'+ objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].confidence +" %" +'</strong></span>' +
                      '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence</strong></span>' +
                    '</a>' +
                  '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
              '</div>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>';
        }
      }
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.collapsible').collapsible();
      });

};
```